# Macro to extract min/max/average data from large data set

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns in my excel file, and I want to get the MIN/Max/Average of the price in the second row based of the information in the first column. i cannot use the normal function as there is 200,000 rows in my workbook.

I have done this before with different data that used the date in the first column now I wish to change it as i am not using  date. I am getting errors in the fist if statement.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long, c As Long, K As Variant
Set Rng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Dn In Rng
    If Not .Exists(DateValue(Dn.Value)) Then
        .Add DateValue(Dn.Value), Dn.Offset(, 1)
    Else
        Set .Item(DateValue(Dn.Value)) = Union(.Item(DateValue(Dn.Value)), Dn.Offset(, 1))
    End If
Next
Range("E1:H1") = Array("Date", "Max", "Min", "Average")
c = 1
For Each K In .keys
    c = c + 1
    Cells(c, "E") = K
    Cells(c, "F") = Application.Max(.Item(K))
    Cells(c, "G") = Application.Min(.Item(K))
    Cells(c, "H") = Application.Average(.Item(K))
Next K
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

MIN/Max/Average of the values in column 2 that relate to the values in column 1

Comment: My answer is [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760202/8112776); I assume "normal" means **worksheet functions**?  ...if the functions aren't functioning properly, could you provide some more information?  Are you  getting an error?

Comment: What output are you seeking as the end result?  If you want to include only rows where a specific column matches a specific value, then use, for example, [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.office.com/article/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690) either as a worksheet function or in VBA (example in answer), or if you want a report showing **all** combinations, it sounds like you're looking for a [**pivot table**](https://support.office.com/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)?

Comment: Sorry im not great with the technical terms i think iv managed to get it working with a pivot table. thanks for the reply tho you where really helpful

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" functions should be working properly regardless of how many rows of data you have.

For example, I just double-checked worksheet functions [`MIN`](https://support.office.com/article/min-function-61635d12-920f-4ce2-a70f-96f202dcc152), [`MAX`](https://support.office.com/article/max-function-e0012414-9ac8-4b34-9a47-73e662c08098), [`AVERAGE`](https://support.office.com/article/average-function-047bac88-d466-426c-a32b-8f33eb960cf6), [`MINIFS`](https://support.office.com/article/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599), [`MAXIFS`](https://support.office.com/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883) and [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.office.com/article/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690) calculated on a column of 200k rows and dependant on the value of another column, and I didn't have any problem (using Excel for Office 365).

---

### Example:

*"Average of `Column B` where `Column A` equals 2"*

**Worksheet function:**

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B, A:A, 2)
```

**VBA [WorksheetFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction):**

```
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(Range("B:B"), Range("A:A"), 2)
```

---

Perhaps you're using an older version of Excel?

As far as I know, all of Excel's functions/formulas will work properly up to the [maximum number of rows/columns](https://support.office.com/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) of that the version can handle (which is **1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns** since at least Excel 2007).